# Searching for a particular kind of field in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to form a query for searching only specific fields, wherein there are numbers after a specific piece of text. To provide an example, I am currently using the following query:

`host="xyz-*" apple "retry *"`

I have to find specific entries that have this in their result: *"retry 1"* or *"retry 2"* or *"retry 3"* etc. up to I don't know how many retries.

But the problem that I'm facing is that the above query is also displaying results which have *"retry banana"*, *"retry mango"*, etc. too.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base query can only use wildcards, like you have already.  To filter more specifically, use the `where` command.

```
host="xyz-*" apple "retry *"
| where match(_raw, "retry \d+")
```